# Properties of non-integer powers of the Hodge Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hodge-theory

Consider a  complete smooth Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.

I think that it is not difficult to prove that the $k$ Hodge Laplacian is essentially selfadjoint in the relevant $L^2$ space of $k$ forms, when defining it on the smooth compactly supported $k$ forms.
The standard argument by Chernoff should apply to this case, too.

I am interested in the validity of identities like this one (maybe on some specific  domain) $$\delta_{k+1}(\Delta_{k+1})^{\alpha} = (\Delta_k)^{\alpha} \delta_{k+1}\tag{1}$$
where $\delta$ is the *closure* of the usual formal adjoint  of $d$ (both defined on the smooth compactly supported forms) and $\Delta$ is the analogous closure (i.e., the unique selfadjoint extension) of the Hodge Laplacian (defined again on smooth compactly supported forms). $\alpha$ is any real. The powers are defined by spectral calculus using the fact that the spectrum of the operator is positive.

For reasons arising from physics, I am quite confident that (1) holds at least when applying both sides to smooth $k+1$-forms with compact support. However I did not manage to find  books or papers on these issues, barring some quite old articles. I am not an expert so I suppose that, simply, I have not searched thoroughly.

A modern reference on these issues would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice question. I think there is a trick that makes it obvious enough not to need a special reference. First, if both sides are to be applied to $k+1$-forms, to be consistent your desired identity needs to be
$$
  \delta_{k+1} (\Delta_{k+1})^{\alpha} = (\Delta_k)^{\alpha} \delta_{k+1} . \tag{1}
$$

The trick consists of starting with the operator $D = d + \delta$, aka the *Hodge-Dirac operator*, which maps the space of all forms to itself. $D$ is obviously symmetric on smooth compactly supported forms. The Hodge-de Rham Laplacian is then $\Delta = D^2$. By block decomposition, $d_k$ is the block of $D$ that maps $k$-forms to $k+1$-forms, $\delta_k$ is the block of $D$ that maps $k$ forms to $k-1$-forms, while $\Delta_k$ is the block of $\Delta$ that maps $k$-forms to $k$-forms. If you can show that $D$ is essentially self-adjoint on the core of smooth forms with compact support, then the desired identity (1) falls out of the block decomposition of the automatic functional-calculus identity
$$
  D |D|^{2\alpha} = |D|^{2\alpha} D .
$$

But $D$ is essentially self-adjoint because $\Delta$ is, since the resolvent of one can be used to construct the resultant of the other by the formula
$$
  \frac{1}{\lambda - D} = \frac{\lambda + D}{\lambda^2 - D^2} .
$$
To make the argument precise, note that the identity $(\lambda - D) \frac{\lambda + D}{\lambda^2 - D^2} = \mathrm{id}$ on smooth compactly supported forms shows that for any non-real $\lambda$ the range of $\lambda - D$ is dense in $L^2$ forms. Hence, by Corollary to Thm.VIII.3(c) in Reed-Simon v.1, $D$ is essentially self-adjoint.

I hope I didn't make a mistake in the last argument. In any case, the essential self-adjointness of $D$ can probably be shown in a more classical way, as it was done for the usual spinor Dirac operator, for instance in

> *Wolf, Joseph A.*, [**Essential self adjointness for the Dirac operator and its square**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1512/iumj.1973.22.22051), Indiana Univ. Math. J. 22, 611-640 (1973). [ZBL0263.58013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0263.58013).

Comment: Hi Igor, thank you very much. Obviously my statement contained a typo (I swapped the indices of $\Delta$ and $\delta$). I will read your answer in details.

Comment: Maybe there is an apparent problem with your last point if I understand well. When you apply $(\lambda-D) \frac{\lambda+D}{\lambda^2-D^2}=id$ to a smooth compactly supported  form, $\lambda-D$ turns out to be evaluated on a smooth (elliptic regularity)  $L^2$ form. But you cannot control the support I suspect. So, the range of $\lambda-D$ is dense (and the operator is ess selfadg as you suggest because the defect indices are trivial) but on smooth $L^2$ forms. However I think this can be fixed and $D$ is ess selfadg on the right domain you said.

Comment: In any cases, I think that $D$ can be proved to be ess selfadg on compactly supported smooth forms by using  standard Chernoff's procedure.

Comment: Ciao Valter, I think you are correct in spotting the problem in my self-adjointness argument. Perhaps the right domain on which it could work is just the "square root" of the domain of $\Delta$. But, as you say, $D$ could be proven to be self-adjoint in some other way, in which case the rest of the argument survives.

Comment: Ciao Igor! Yes, one can use  Chernoff's argument. One constructs an ultrastatic spacetime and consider a Dirac equation where $D$ is the spatial operator.  This equation, by causality, transforms compactly supported smooth initial conditions to compactly supported initial conditions.

Comment: On the other hand, this evolution can be proved  to be  due to a strongly continuous unitary group on the right Hilbert space of initial data. This group leaves invariant the space of compactly supported smooth initial data. As a corollary of Stone's theorem this is a core for the generator of the group (and all its integer positive powers) which is just $-iD$. So $D$ is essentially selfadjoint on that space.

Comment: Ciao Igor. Eventually I decided to follow another (a bit different) route, because some details turned out to be a bit awkward to deal with. However your suggestions pointed out the general strategy to me. Your name will appear in the acknowledgments of the paper I am completing. I would like to point out you this very nice paper on related subjects J. Br\"uning and M. Lesch, Hilbert Complexes. J. Functional Analysis {\bf 108}, 88-132 (1992)